# How to modify filter condition of a queueitem view dynamically

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Simon Hutson says in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukcrm/archive/2011/03/10/using-plug-ins-to-modify-views.aspx?Redirected=true) blog that "*Every time you access a view in CRM user interface, it causes the CRM platform to execute a query by raising a RetrieveMultiple request. A plug-in that intercepts this request, can modify the query before it is executed by the CRM platform*".

I want to intercept view request of queueitem entity in a plugin and modify it but the problem is there is **no RetrieveMultiple message for queueitem** entity in PluginRegistration tool. How can I modify filter condition of a queueitem view dynamically?

**Question updated after Henk reply:**

I have created a personal view in queueitem entity. One of the filter criteria in that personal view is based on a custom field of queueitem entity:

```
custom_field    Equals    10
```

I want to change the value of 10 with some other integer value dynamically i.e. when the view loads. Views of queueitem entity gets loaded on the click of Queue entity in the left navigation area of sitemap.

As Henk suggested, I have registered a plugin on RetrieveMultiple message for all of the entities on Pre-validation step. Inside that plugin, I used the code provided by Henk below:

```
var query = (QueryExpression) context.InputParameters["Query"];
```

When I click on Queue entity in the left navigation area of sitemap, my plugin runs 3 times for the entities: queue, userquery and savedquery.

These 3 entity names I got using **query.EntityName** property inside the plugin. 
Now the problem is I am not getting queueitem entity here which means my plugin is not executing for queueitem. Because of this problem I am not able to use below line of code to update the filter criteria of queueitem's view:

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("custom_field", ConditionOperator.Equal, 500);
```

And if I tried to run this code anyways in the plugin for any of the above mentioned 3 entities i.e. **queue, userquery and savedquery**, I got an **error** *"The specified field does not exist in Microsoft Dynamics CRM"* which seems logical to me as "custom_field" exist in queueitem entity not in any of these 3 entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to register the RetrieveMultiple message for a specific entity. If you do not specify an entity at all, the plugin will be triggered for any RetrieveMultiple request issued to Dynamics CRM.

You can modify the QueryExpression's criteria in the PreValidation step.

In the basic example below queries for the account entity are intercepted. The code adds a condition that forces the query to only return active account records. (Keep in mind this is not a complete solution, since the account entity can also be part of LinkEntity collections.)

```
var context = (IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IPluginExecutionContext));

var query = (QueryExpression) context.InputParameters["Query"];

if (query.EntityName != "account")
    return;

if (query.Criteria.FilterOperator == LogicalOperator.Or)
{
    FilterExpression childFilter = query.Criteria;
    query.Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
    query.Criteria.AddFilter(childFilter);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0);
    return;
}

ConditionExpression condition = query.Criteria.Conditions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AttributeName == "statecode");

if (condition == null)
{
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0);
    return;
}

condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
condition.Values.Clear();
condition.Values.Add(0);
return;
```

You do not need to save the QueryExpression or replace it in the InputParameters collection. The modified query will simply be passed further down the plugin execution pipeline.

**RetrieveMultiple & entity queueitem**

I ran a few tests on a plugin registered for the RetrieveMultiple message and found that the event is not triggered for entity queueitem. So, while the code above does work for a number of entities (including custom entities), it appears we have to take into account that there are exceptions regarding some built-in entities.

I also registered a plugin on the Execute message (which used to be triggered for FetchXml requests), but had no luck either. Queries on entity queueitem can not be intercepted in plugins, it seems.

Comment: it's better to don't register a plugin on every RetrieveMultiple (performance issues)

Comment: As a rule of thumb it is wise to be careful, but sometimes you have no better options. When your plugin is designed well you can minimize the overhead involved. It comes down to determine as early as possible if the plugin event at hand has to be processed. As long as no I/O is involved in memory processing does not have to have a noticable impact on performance.

Comment: Hi Henk,I registered the plugin on RetrieveMultiple message with "Primary Entity" text box set to blank and plugin executed successfully.
In the plugin code, context.InputParameters does not hold any value for "Target" but holds value for "Query" instead which seems fine to me as this plugin got executed on the call of a view. 
Can you please suggest me how can I use context.InputParameters["Query"] to intercept the desired view of queueitem entity in order to change its filter condition?

Comment: I will extend my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the code Henk. But it still does not solve my problem. I have updated my question above.

Comment: I tried my approach on queueitem myself and had no luck either. I updated my answer. Sorry, I could not help you.

Comment: At least you confirmed that queueitem entity's view cannot be modified dynamically. I'll mark your reply as an answer until someone else gives a better solution. Thanks